# How to get a monitor value in Arduino

Tags: type-conversion, arduino-uno

I am programming on arduino UNO and my school project is about GPS and GSM lcoalisation. I already coded something for GSM, but I don't manage to convert the latitude (float) in a char.

My code:

```
//global variable

char msg[30];                       //define the  message variable

//dans le loop

if (gsmloc_success) {

      Serial.print(F("GSMLoc lat:"));

      Serial.println(latitude, 6);

      sprintf (msg,"%f",latitude);

      Serial.println(msg); //here I get a "?" in the output
```

Comment: Could you please modify your question to include a more comprehensive view of your code? what device are you using to collect GPS/GSM data? how did you connect them to your arduino device?

Comment: yea i dont get anything from the data you have given.

Comment: I use fona sim808 GSM/GPS.My principal problem is to show in the serial monitor a float value.because I want to put it in a variable and sent i in a message text.The variable "latitude" content the latitude of my position.His type is float.my problem come to the "sprintf" xho are suppose to convert latitude in to msg ( char variable).this convertion don't work I don't know why?

Comment: I have found how to do it.                                                                                       if (gsmloc_success) {
      Serial.print(F("GSMLoc lat:"));    
      Serial.println(latitude, 6);
      String lat=String(latitude,6);
      Serial.print(F("GSMLoc long:"));
      Serial.println(longitude, 6);
       String lon=String(longitude,6);
       String Msg="";
       Msg=lat+";"+lon;
         Serial.println(Msg);
         char* msg;
             msg = (char*)Msg.c_str();
             Serial.println( msg);